# Bundle Options Price Dispayed wong in the cart after Observer Event

Tags: cart, group-price

We used event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` for update group price in cart page.

we get proper group price in event but, after event go to the cart page at that time Bundle Option price displayed wrong (Not displayed Group price ).

```
public function changePrice($observer) {

        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $item = $event->getQuoteItem();

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        $selectedCustomerEmail = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMySessionVariable();   

        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");                      
                    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                    $customer->loadByEmail($selectedCustomerEmail);

        $customerGroupId = $customer->getGroupId(); 

        $grp_price = $product->getData('group_price'); 


        $group_price = $grp_price[$customerGroupId]['price'];

        $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode(); 
        $currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

        $priceTwo = Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($group_price, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode);

        $finalPrice = $priceTwo;



        if($finalPrice > 0){
            $item->setCustomPrice($finalPrice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            $item->save();
        }

        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($finalPrice);   
    }
```

Comment: can you put your observer code at here , otherwise its very tough to help you

Comment: Hello @MurtuzaZabuawala if you have any idea then please share here.